# Iterate through multiple, multidemsional arrays and output json

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays and I need two create a seperate array or alter the first one with data from 2nd array. using similar fields with different names for reference. I need to search through array 2 till I find the `root_server_url` field that matches with array 1 `root_server_uri` field. once there I want to take the `name` field from array 2 and add it to the end of array1 or separate array with all those fields. I think I might be over (or under) thinking this. both arrays are fed from two different json api calls. all of the URIs are unique.

*Array 1*

```
(
    [8] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => 34.3025556
            [longitude] => -77.4598012
            [weekday_tinyint] => 4
            [start_time] => 19:00:00
            [meeting_name] => On Time
            [root_server_uri] => https://example.com/server/unique
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => 37.5050744
            [longitude] => -73.5075403
            [weekday_tinyint] => 4
            [start_time] => 19:00:00
            [meeting_name] => Robot
            [root_server_uri] => http://www.example.org/server/
        )

)
```

*Array 2*

```
(   
    [35] => Array
        (
            [url] => https://example.org/rest/v1/
            [root_server_url] => https://example.com/server/unique
            [name] => Kentucky
            [num_regions] => 2
            [num_areas] => 13
            [num_meetings] => 548
            [server_info] => [{"version": "2.10.7", "versionInt": "2010007}]
            [last_successful_import] => 2018-10-15T20:00:12.952796Z
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [url] => https://example.org/rest/v1/
            [root_server_url] => http://www.example.org/server/
            [name] => San Jose
            [num_regions] => 0
            [num_areas] => 2
            [num_meetings] => 145
            [server_info] => [{"version": "2.10.5", "versionInt": "2010005"}]
            [last_successful_import] => 2018-10-15T19:55:23.045540Z
        )

)
```

I would like my final array to look like this
*Final Array*

```
(
    [8] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => 34.3025556
            [longitude] => -77.4598012
            [weekday_tinyint] => 4
            [start_time] => 19:00:00
            [meeting_name] => On Time
            [root_server_uri] => https://example.com/server/unique
            [name] => Kentucky
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => 37.5050744
            [longitude] => -73.5075403
            [weekday_tinyint] => 4
            [start_time] => 19:00:00
            [meeting_name] => Robot
            [root_server_uri] => http://www.example.org/server/
            [name] => San Jose
        )

)
```

this is the code I have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$root_server = "https://example.org/rest/v1/";
$meetings_respone = get($root_server . "/json/&data_field_key=latitude,longitude,weekday_tinyint,start_time,meeting_name");
$meetings = json_decode($meetings_respone, true);
$rootServers_respone = get($root_server . "/rest/v1/rootservers/");
$rootServers = json_decode($rootServers_respone, true);

    foreach ($unique_meetings as $meeting) {
        foreach ($rootServers as $rootServer) {
            if (strtolower($rootServer['root_server_url']) == $meeting['root_server_uri']) {
               $name = $rootServer['name'];
            }
        }
        echo '{latitude: ' . $meeting['latitude']
        . ', longitude: ' . $meeting['longitude']
        . ', weekday_tinyint: \'' . $meeting['weekday_tinyint']
        . ' \', start_time: \'' . $meeting['start_time']
        . '\', meeting_name: \'' . $meeting['meeting_name']
        . '\', root_server_uri: \'' . $meeting['root_server_uri']
        . '\', name: \'' . $name . '\''
        . '},' . "\n";
    }

function get($url) {
    error_log($url);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $errorno = curl_errno($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($errorno > 0) {
        throw new Exception(curl_strerror($errorno));
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Are these arrays nested or something? Because they aren’t multidimensional as I see it?

Comment: yes im sorry im new here and as soon as i posted, I couldn't figure out how to edit it. still can't...

Comment: I might help you tomorrow, if the answer isn’t provided already ofcourse. ;)

Comment: I don't see any attempt to create an array here. I see some echoing of strings and that's about it.

Comment: Yes the echoing of the strings gets dumped to JSON file I can then use

Comment: However I prob should just use an array and not bother with dumping back to JSON

Answer (score 0):

This will be a lot easier if you reindex array 1 by the unique column 'root_server_uri'.

```
$array1 = array_column($array1, null, 'root_server_uri');
```

Then you can iterate array 2 and append the names using the matching keys.

```
foreach($array2 as $item) {
    $array1[$item['root_server_url']]['name'] = $item['name'];
}
```

If there are multiple matching entries in array 2, you can append the names to an array at 'name' instead of assigning the value directly, so you can collect them all.

```
$array1[$item['root_server_url']]['name'][] = $item['name'];
```

If you need to keep the original keys from array 1, you can get a copy of them before reindexing with

```
$keys = array_keys($array1);
```

And then put them back after adding the names with

```
$array1 = array_combine($keys, $array1);
```

The keys and values should still match up because you're not adding/removing any items from array 1 or doing anything that will change the order.

If the original keys don't matter, you can remove the string keys with `array_values` if you don't want them.

```
$array1 = array_values($array1);
```

Comment: doesn't `array_column` requires the indices to be on the root level? IMHO the `array1` needs to be `$array1( array(''latitude'' => '', 'longitude' = '') , array(''latitude'' => '', 'longitude' = ''))` not `$array1( 8 => array(''latitude'' => '', 'longitude' = '') , 16 => array(''latitude'' => '', 'longitude' = ''))`

Comment: Thank yo so much for the help. I tried that and didn't work the root_server_url field in array 2 is always unique and always only one of them, the final array must contain all fields from array1 plus the name field like shown in final array example. anyways still playing with it.

Comment: it keeps saying array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: actually the 2nd comment was my mistake, operator error.

Comment: this worked but only for the same number of arrays in both aaray1 and array2, I should of mentioned array1 has like 1,000 arrays in it and array2 has 36

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll have to take another look tomorrow. I'm not at my computer any more.

Comment: no problem my fault should of mentioned that, just joined stack. but it worked great besides that. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using array search to find the unique key value in array 2 that matched array 1. from there I knew my matching keys and I could assign name from array2 properly to array 1.

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $keyfind = array_search($array1[$key]['root_server_uri'], array_column($array2, 'root_server_url'));
    $array1[$key]['name'] = $array2[$keyfind]['name'];
}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do it, but it worked for me.